# VIM possible to detect multiple languages on same file

Tags: javascript, html, css, vim

Is VIM able to detect multiple languages on same file? Sometimes I am prototyping and I dump HTML/CSS/JS/PHP on the same page and to use the right language I must run : setf xlangx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Different syntax highlighting within regions of a file`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip857) Vim Wikia tip.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @anythingispossible: I dabbled with this myself about a year ago. It seemed to work fairly well (though I haven't actually had a need for it since).