# Twig files: syntax hightlighting for html and twig parts

Tags: vim

Twig files (.twig) combine twig structure and html code. Im wondering if it is possible to get syntax highlighting for both types of code in the same file.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162221/how-to-syntax-highlight-a-part-of-file-in-a-different-syntax

Comment: ... and these: [VIM possible to detect multiple languages on same file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8784083), [Mixing two syntax highlighting scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16201896).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact approach depends on how the Twig and HTML syntaxes are combined. This is an old problem, and you'll find several syntaxes in the default runtime that include the HTML syntax, e.g. *htmldjango*, *markdown*, *php*.

Besides, a quick search for "twig vim syntax" brings up [this](http://aaronbonner.io/post/16914552864/enable-syntax-highlighting-for-twig-templates-in-vim) and [this](https://github.com/evidens/vim-twig). Should solve your problem, right?!

Comment: thanks, htmljinja syntax works, but I don't get the correct indentation when I type `gg=G`. All the lines go to the first column of the file. I have this line for that: `autocmd FileType htmljinja setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2`.  For the .htmljinja files the indentation works ok. I get also this output: `noautoindent
nosmartindent
nocindent
  indentexpr=`